# Why is the "better" digit-listing function slower?

Tags: performance, haskell

I was playing around with Project Euler #34, and I wrote these functions:

```
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
import Data.Char

digits :: (Integral a) => a -> [Int]
digits x
    | x < 10 = [fromIntegral x]
    | otherwise = let (q, r) = x `quotRem` 10 in (fromIntegral r) : (digits q)

digitsByShow :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> [Int]
digitsByShow = map (\x -> ord x - ord '0') . show
```

I thought that for sure `digits` has to be the faster one, as we don't convert to a String. I could not have been more wrong. I ran the two versions via `pe034`:

```
pe034 digitFunc = sum $ filter sumFactDigit [3..2540160]
    where
        sumFactDigit :: Int -> Bool
        sumFactDigit n = n == (sum $ map sFact $ digitFunc n)
        sFact :: Int -> Int
        sFact n
            | n == 0 = 1
            | n == 1 = 1
            | n == 2 = 2
            | n == 3 = 6
            | n == 4 = 24
            | n == 5 = 120
            | n == 6 = 720
            | n == 7 = 5040
            | n == 8 = 40320
            | n == 9 = 362880

main = do
    begin <- getPOSIXTime
    print $ pe034 digitsByShow -- or digits
    end <- getPOSIXTime
    print $ end - begin
```

After compiling with `ghc -O`, `digits` consistently takes .5 seconds, while `digitsByShow` consistently takes .3 seconds. Why is this so? Why is the function which stays within Integer arithmetic slower, whereas the function which goes into string comparison is faster?

I ask this because I come from programming in Java and similar languages, where the `% 10` trick of generating digits is way faster than the "convert to String" method. I haven't been able to wrap my head around the fact that converting to a string could be faster.

Comment: Are you running compiled code? Are you comparing an interpreted `digits` to calling `show` which will run compiled code?

Comment: @user5402 I think I was not running compiled code. Trying now.

Comment: Try redefining `digits :: Int -> [Int]`, if that is legal within the realm of the question of course.

Comment: @Kwarrtz That speeds it up, but not by that much, and also it's required that I can find the digits of numbers such as `2^1000` or `100!`.

Comment: In that case, I think `digitsWithShow` is faster here for no other reason than that `show` already does almost what you are trying to do. Int to string conversion is a very low level operation (assembler on some processors, I think). Just out of curiosity, have you tried `digitsByShow = map read . show`? I'd think it should be slower, but then again...

Comment: @Kwarrtz `map read . show` doesn't work, neither does `(map read) . show`. Seems that `read` only works on a String, not a Char, so it's expecting `show` to return `[String]` but of course it returns `String`.

Comment: Oh, of course. I meant `map (read . (:[])) . show`.

Comment: Why are you doing the division twice? `let (q,r) = quotRem x 10 in ...`

Comment: @recursion.ninja I figured that out. I forgot to edit it in, but I did figure it out. I'll edit in the improvements I've found.

Comment: @Kwarrtz With `-O`, the execution time of that method is about 30 seconds. That's about 60 times slower than `digitsByShow`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with.

```
digitsV2 :: (Integral a) => a -> [Int]
digitsV2 n = go n []
    where
      go x xs
          | x < 10    = fromIntegral x : xs
          | otherwise = case quotRem x 10 of
                  (q,r) -> go q (fromIntegral r : xs)
```

when compiled with `-O2` and tested with Criterion

`digits`       runs in 470.4 ms

`digitsByShow` runs in 421.8 ms

`digitsV2`     runs in 258.0 ms

results may vary

edit:
I am not sure why building the list like this helps so much.
But you can improve your codes speed by strictly evaluating `quotRem x 10`

You can do this with BangPatterns

```
| otherwise = let !(q, r) = x `quotRem` 10 in (fromIntegral r) : (digits q)
```

or with case

```
| otherwise = case quotRem x 10 of
                (q,r) -> fromIntegral r : digits q
```

Doing this drops `digits` down to 323.5 ms

edit: time without using Criterion

digits = 464.3 ms

digitsStrict = 328.2 ms

digitsByShow = 259.2 ms

digitV2 = 252.5 ms

note: The criterion package measures software performance.

Comment: What about this makes it faster? Why is my version slower? Does this have something to do with mutability?

Comment: The bang pattern barely sped anything up for me.

Comment: @Justin It works for me. Where did you put it , `!(q,r)` or `digits !x` the second one did not help.

Comment: I copied exactly the code you wrote. It sped it up, but not by nearly as much as you suggested.

Comment: Looking at your benchmarks, it actually does sound proportional to the results I'm getting. Thank you. PS Do you know if there is a good way to disassemble haskell code (at different points)?

Comment: You can use `-ddump-simpl` to look at the core code. real world haskell talks about it on ch 25 [Link](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html)

Comment: You can also tell GHC to spit out assembly. `-S`, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Let's investigate why [@No_signal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32217316/1896169) is faster.

I made three runs of ghc:

```
ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl digits.hs >digits.txt
ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl digitsV2.hs >digitsV2.txt
ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl show.hs >show.txt
```

*`digits.hs`*

```
digits :: (Integral a) => a -> [Int]
digits x
    | x < 10 = [fromIntegral x]
    | otherwise = let (q, r) = x `quotRem` 10 in (fromIntegral r) : (digits q)

main = return $ digits 1
```

*`digitsV2.hs`*

```
digitsV2 :: (Integral a) => a -> [Int]
digitsV2 n = go n []
    where
      go x xs
          | x < 10    = fromIntegral x : xs
          | otherwise = let (q, r) = x `quotRem` 10 in go q (fromIntegral r : xs)

main = return $ digits 1
```

*`show.hs`*

```
import Data.Char

digitsByShow :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> [Int]
digitsByShow = map (\x -> ord x - ord '0') . show

main = return $ digitsByShow 1
```

If you'd like to view the complete txt files, I placed them on ideone (rather than paste a 10000 char dump here):

- [digits.txt](http://ideone.com/dIfhY7)
- [digitsV2.txt](http://ideone.com/SIKzQE)
- [show.txt](http://ideone.com/7CbZ2y)

---

If we carefully look through *`digits.txt`*, it appears that this is the relevant section:

```
lvl_r1qU = __integer 10

Rec {
Main.$w$sdigits [InlPrag=[0], Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: Integer -> (# Int, [Int] #)
[GblId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType <S,U>]
Main.$w$sdigits =
  \ (w_s1pI :: Integer) ->
    case integer-gmp-1.0.0.0:GHC.Integer.Type.ltInteger#
           w_s1pI lvl_r1qU
    of wild_a17q { __DEFAULT ->
    case GHC.Prim.tagToEnum# @ Bool wild_a17q of _ [Occ=Dead] {
      False ->
        let {
          ds_s16Q [Dmd=<L,U(U,U)>] :: (Integer, Integer)
          [LclId, Str=DmdType]
          ds_s16Q =
            case integer-gmp-1.0.0.0:GHC.Integer.Type.quotRemInteger
                   w_s1pI lvl_r1qU
            of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv_a17D, ipv1_a17E #) ->
            (ipv_a17D, ipv1_a17E)
            } } in
        (# case ds_s16Q of _ [Occ=Dead] { (q_a11V, r_X12h) ->
           case integer-gmp-1.0.0.0:GHC.Integer.Type.integerToInt r_X12h
           of wild3_a17c { __DEFAULT ->
           GHC.Types.I# wild3_a17c
           }
           },
           case ds_s16Q of _ [Occ=Dead] { (q_X12h, r_X129) ->
           case Main.$w$sdigits q_X12h
           of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ww1_s1pO, ww2_s1pP #) ->
           GHC.Types.: @ Int ww1_s1pO ww2_s1pP
           }
           } #);
      True ->
        (# GHC.Num.$fNumInt_$cfromInteger w_s1pI, GHC.Types.[] @ Int #)
    }
    }
end Rec }
```

*`digitsV2.txt`*:

```
lvl_r1xl = __integer 10

Rec {
Main.$wgo [InlPrag=[0], Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: Integer -> [Int] -> (# Int, [Int] #)
[GblId, Arity=2, Str=DmdType <S,U><L,U>]
Main.$wgo =
  \ (w_s1wh :: Integer) (w1_s1wi :: [Int]) ->
    case integer-gmp-1.0.0.0:GHC.Integer.Type.ltInteger#
           w_s1wh lvl_r1xl
    of wild_a1dp { __DEFAULT ->
    case GHC.Prim.tagToEnum# @ Bool wild_a1dp of _ [Occ=Dead] {
      False ->
        case integer-gmp-1.0.0.0:GHC.Integer.Type.quotRemInteger
               w_s1wh lvl_r1xl
        of _ [Occ=Dead] { (# ipv_a1dB, ipv1_a1dC #) ->
        Main.$wgo
          ipv_a1dB
          (GHC.Types.:
             @ Int
             (case integer-gmp-1.0.0.0:GHC.Integer.Type.integerToInt ipv1_a1dC
              of wild2_a1ea { __DEFAULT ->
              GHC.Types.I# wild2_a1ea
              })
             w1_s1wi)
        };
      True -> (# GHC.Num.$fNumInt_$cfromInteger w_s1wh, w1_s1wi #)
    }
    }
end Rec }
```

I actually couldn't find the relevant section for *`show.txt`*. I'll work on that later.

Right off the bat, *`digitsV2.hs`* produces shorter code. That's probably a good sign for it.

*`digits.hs`* seems to be following this psuedocode:

```python
def digits(w_s1pI):
    if w_s1pI < 10: return [fromInteger(w_s1pI)]
    else:
        ds_s16Q = quotRem(w_s1pI, 10)
        q_X12h = ds_s16Q[0]
        r_X12h = ds_s16Q[1]
        wild3_a17c = integerToInt(r_X12h)

        ww1_s1pO = r_X12h
        ww2_s1pP = digits(q_X12h)
        ww2_s1pP.pushFront(ww1_s1pO)
        return ww2_s1pP
```

*`digitsV2.hs`* seems to be following this psuedocode:

```python
def digitsV2(w_s1wh, w1_s1wi=[]): # actually disguised as go(), as @No_signal wrote
    if w_s1wh < 10:
        w1_s1wi.pushFront(fromInteger(w_s1wh))
        return w1_s1wi
    else:
        ipv_a1dB, ipv1_a1dC = quotRem(w_s1wh, 10)
        w1_s1wi.pushFront(integerToIn(ipv1a1dC))
        return digitsV2(ipv1_a1dC, w1_s1wi)
```

It might not be that these functions mutate lists like my psuedocode suggests, but this immediately suggests something: it looks as if `digitsV2` is fully tail-recursive, whereas `digits` is actually not (may have to use some Haskell trampoline or something). It appears as if Haskell needs to store all the remainders in `digits` before pushing them all to the front of the list, whereas it can just push them and forget about them in `digitsV2`. This is purely speculation, but it is well-founded speculation.